# Using signal() inside handler function

Tags: event-handling, signals, handler

I have taken this example from GNU library. And I wonder why they call signal() function twice, first time in main() when setting up the signal handler and second time inside handler function itself.

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* This flag controls termination of the main loop. */
volatile sig_atomic_t keep_going = 1;

/* The signal handler just clears the flag and re-enables itself. */
void
catch_alarm (int sig)
{
  keep_going = 0;
  signal (sig, catch_alarm);
}

void
do_stuff (void)
{
  puts ("Doing stuff while waiting for alarm....");
}

int
main (void)
{
  /* Establish a handler for SIGALRM signals. */
  signal (SIGALRM, catch_alarm);

  /* Set an alarm to go off in a little while. */
  alarm (2);

  /* Check the flag once in a while to see when to quit. */
  while (keep_going)
    do_stuff ();

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now my code...

```
 void createTimer(long freq_nanosec)
 {
    timer_t timerid;
    struct sigevent sev;
    struct itimerspec timerint;
    struct sigaction saction;

    /* Establish handler for timer signal */
    saction.sa_flags = 0;
    saction.sa_handler = OnTimer;
    sigemptyset(&saction.sa_mask);
    sigaddset (&saction.sa_mask, SIGIO);
    if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &saction, NULL) == -1) error("sigaction");
    else printf("OnTimer handler created\n");

    /* Create real time signal */
    sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    sev.sigev_signo = SIGALRM;
    sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
    if (timer_create(CLOCKID, &sev, &timerid) == -1) error("timer_create");
    else printf("timer ID is 0x%lx\n", (long) timerid);

    /* Arm the timer */
    timerint.it_value.tv_sec = timerint.it_interval.tv_sec =
        freq_nanosec / 1000000000;
    timerint.it_value.tv_nsec = timerint.it_interval.tv_nsec = 
        freq_nanosec % 1000000000;
    if (timer_settime(timerid, 0, &timerint, NULL) == -1)                     
               error("timer_settime");
    else printf("Timer armed\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/signal) for `signal`, we see that when a signal arrives:

> first either the disposition is reset to SIG_DFL, or the signal is blocked (see Portability below), and then handler is called with argument signum.

So after the signal arrives, further signals will revert to default behavior. In your sample code, the handler is choosing to re-set the signal handler so further signals will be handled in the same manner as the first.

This is noted in the comment for the function `catch_alarm` in the code you found.

Comment: Does it mean that whenever signal handler is called this signal action is released to default? It is strange because when I use timer signal every time calls handler again and again. And I do not reinstate timer signal inside  the handler. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: How do you set up the handler for the timer signal?

Answer (score 0):

There are two popular versions of `signal`, which differ in whether the disposition of a signal is reset to the default when the handler is called, and whether a signal is blocked for the duration of its handler's execution.

The [standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/signal.html) says those two behaviors are implementation-defined. The first code sample

```
void
catch_alarm (int sig)
{
  keep_going = 0;
  signal (sig, catch_alarm);
}
```

is assuming that the implementation may reset the signal disposition to the default when the handler is called. That's like calling `signal(sig, SIG_DFL)` in the first line of the handler. You almost never want that, because the next time a `SIGALRM` signal comes in, the default action is for the program to be killed. So the handler calls `signal(sig, catch_alarm)` to re-establish itself as the handler.

Your second code sample

```
saction.sa_flags = 0;
saction.sa_handler = OnTimer;
sigemptyset(&saction.sa_mask);
sigaddset (&saction.sa_mask, SIGIO);
if (sigaction(SIGALRM, &saction, NULL) == -1) error("sigaction");
```

uses [`sigaction`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/sigaction.html), which is generally preferred over `signal` because you can specify exactly the behavior you want. The standard says

> new applications should use sigaction() rather than signal().

When `.sa_flags` has the `SA_RESETHAND` flag on, the disposition of the signal is reset to the default when the handler starts, just like in (one version of) `signal`.

But in your case, that flag is off because you set `.sa_flags` to 0, so you don't need to write any code to re-establish the handler.

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I still don't understand with first part. If default action already set as handler calling reset to default already keeps handler calling as default. Why does one need to specifically call catch_alarm to reset thing already in place. Or I miss something?
Also I thot that SA_RESETHAND is a by-default flag, doesn't it?

Comment: By "reset signal disposition to the default", I mean "do the same as `signal(sig,SIG_DFL)`". For most signals, including SIGALRM,  that means the next time the signal is received by the program, the program will be killed. There are no default flags for `sigaction`. You have to pass the `sa_flags` member to it every time. If you specify a signal handler, sigaction will behave differently when `SA_RESETHAND` is on versus when it's off.